# Renaming Auto Layout Constraints in XCode14 Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

It seems like you cannot rename the layout constraints in the IB side-menu for easier reference. Double-clicking on it does not seem to fix it nor is there an option to rename the constraint in the right-hand side menu

Any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can still change the constraint's label in the Identity inspector:

[image]

Outcode:

[image]

Nonetheless, it isn't entirely clear what useful purpose it serves to give a constraint a name in the document outline; this would only obscures the useful information already provided (i.e. a *description* of the constraint). If you want to know what constraint is being referred to, just look in the canvas after selecting (as in your screenshot).

You could give the *button* or the *stack view* a more useful name, and it would then show up in the constraint reference in the document outline.

The place to give a constraint a name is in the attributes inspector:

[image]

This is useful because the identifier name will appear in, say, constraint conflict reports, the view debugger, and so forth.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It sounds like you work with a large desktop monitor and plenty of real estate. It's tough out here in the 13" world of PCs

Comment: Actually no. But I do have many techniques for dealing with the smallness of the screen.

Comment: I found a way to change it. See revised answer. But I stand by my objections. :)